# Can I load a WCF configuration in xml during execution?

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-4.0, wcf-client

I want to create a client proxy using an endpoint configuration name.  Prior to proxy creation, I want to take the configuration in XML and load it into memory.  Its not an option to specify this configuration in app.config.  Also, its not an option to create the configuration programmatically (like actually instantiating the endpoint, binding, etc. objects).  Given these constraints, I'm assuming that I have to somehow interact with .net's configuration manager?  Ideally, I could tell the configuration manager to load data from a chunk of xml with the parent elment being <system.serviceModel>.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure so I am not posting this as answer. WCF is tightly coupled to configuration in assembly configuration file. There are no method allowing you to pass just configuration section so unless you want to parse configuration by yourselves and create setting in code based on parsed data you will not able to do that.

Comment: I don't know of any way, in general, to redirect the reading of configuration to memory. It's not designed that way.